# twisted Get response data at client

Tags: python, twisted, twisted.web, twisted.client

I followed this [tutorial](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/10.2.0/web/howto/client.html) but I don't know how to get response data from server.

```
class Service(Resource):
    def render_POST(self, request):
        return 'response message'
```

I know that the response data will be displayed in the client

```
 def dataReceived(self, bytes):
        if self.remaining:
            display = bytes[:self.remaining]
            print 'Some data received:'
            print display
            self.remaining -= len(display)
```

How can I get the returned message from server and store it into a variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just make `dataReceived` store `display` in an instance variable, and append to it every time `dataReceived` is called. Then, once `connectionLost` is called, you know you have the complete response.

```
class BeginningPrinter(Protocol):
    def __init__(self, finished):
        self.finished = finished
        self.remaining = 1024 * 10
        self.total_response = ""  # This will store the response.

    def dataReceived(self, bytes):
        if self.remaining:
            display = bytes[:self.remaining]
            self.total_response += display  # Append to our response.
            self.remaining -= len(display)

    def connectionLost(self, reason):
        print 'Finished receiving body:', reason.getErrorMessage()
        print 'response is ',self.total_response
        self.finished.callback(self.total_response)
```

In the context of the full example:

```
from pprint import pformat

from twisted.internet import reactor
from twisted.internet.defer import Deferred
from twisted.internet.protocol import Protocol
from twisted.web.client import Agent
from twisted.web.http_headers import Headers

class BeginningPrinter(Protocol):
    def __init__(self, finished):
        self.finished = finished
        self.remaining = 1024 * 10
        self.total_response = ""  # This will store the response.

    def dataReceived(self, bytes):
        if self.remaining:
            display = bytes[:self.remaining]
            self.total_response += display  # Append to our response.
            self.remaining -= len(display)

    def connectionLost(self, reason):
        print 'Finished receiving body:', reason.getErrorMessage()
        print 'response is ',self.total_response
        self.finished.callback(self.total_response)  # Executes all registered callbacks

def handle_result(response):
    print("Got response {}".format(response)

agent = Agent(reactor)
d = agent.request(
    'GET',
    'http://example.com/',
    Headers({'User-Agent': ['Twisted Web Client Example']}),
    None)

def cbRequest(response):
    print 'Response version:', response.version
    print 'Response code:', response.code
    print 'Response phrase:', response.phrase
    print 'Response headers:'
    print pformat(list(response.headers.getAllRawHeaders()))
    finished = Deferred()
    finished.addCallback(handle_result)  # handle_result will be called when the response is ready
    response.deliverBody(BeginningPrinter(finished))
    return finished
d.addCallback(cbRequest)

def cbShutdown(ignored):
    reactor.stop()
d.addBoth(cbShutdown)

reactor.run()
```

Comment: Thanks dano, but how if I want to store the data in a variable that is outside of the BeginningPrinter class? I mean, the data you get is still inside that class.

Comment: @coderkisser That's what the `finished` `Deferred` can be used for. I've expanded my answer to demonstrate.

Comment: I still can't get the data in a variable because you get it to a function. I need something like: message = handle_result(). Please kindly to help.

Comment: @coderkisser Why do you need that? Programs written with twisted are organized differently from regular programs. The "twisted" way to do something with the response would be to register a callback. It doesn't really make sense to do it any other way, since the whole program runs inside the reactor.